# Embedding of a subgroup into a group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, normal-subgroups

What does embedding a group into another group mean for the group generators? Can you please explain with an example. I would like to know what it means for $SU(3)$ to be embedded in $SU(3)\times SU(3)$ in terms of the generators (in matrix form).

Comment: I think this question is too general in its present form. You can always embed A group $G$ in $G \times G$ by mapping it to $G \times \{e\}$, or with the diagonal map. Other ways too.  If you have some particular context in mind please edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the concept of embedding. What does it mean to embed $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ in $SU(6)$. How do the generators map and what do the leftover generators of $SU(6)$ do? Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the question you've asked, but probably not the question you are trying to ask.

The concept is straightforward: an embedding is just an injective homomorphism. Any particular embedding maps the generators to wherever they go. Asking about the "leftover generators" in the codomain makes no sense.

Your comment seems to ask about "the embedding". There are many. If there's a particular one you care about (presumably because of its origin in physics) you should edit the question to tell us what it is, and ask a partcular question that puzzles you.

Comment: okay, thanks. Can you tell me how I would write down the map for diagonal embedding of $SU(N)$ into $SU(N)\times SU(N)$. That would bring some clarity to me.

Comment: @MD The diagonal map is just $g \mapsto (g,g)$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: No. What would the map be for the group elements? Suppose $U$ is the first $SU(N)$ matrix and $V$ is the second $SU(N)$ matrix and $W$ is the diagonally embedded $SU(N)$ matrix. How to write the map as a function of $W$ (and $U$ and $V$)?. This map is generally denoted by $\iota$.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing the "diagonal embedding" with something else? The diagonal embedding is a function $f : SU(N) \to SU(N) \times SU(N)$. The input is a **single** matrix $U \in SU(N)$. The output $f(U)$ is an ordered pair of matrices $f(U)=(U,U) \in SU(N) \times SU(N)$. The first entry of the ordered pair $(U,U)$ is the matrix $U$, regarded as an element of the first $SU(N)$ factor in the product $SU(N) \times SU(N)$. The second entry of the ordered pair $(U,U)$ is the matrix $U$, regarded as an element of the second $SU(N)$ factor in the product $SU(N) \times SU(N)$.

Comment: @MD I suppose it is denoted by $i$ since it is just the inclusion map:  the diagonal is a subset of the cross-product...